# Password fields on Mac won't allow more than 3 characters

Tags: keyboard, password

When Skype asked to enter my password it would not allow me to enter the full password.

Skype simply stopped registering the keystrokes after 3 characters. I restarted the Mac but now the same problem is happening with my login password. I can enter the first 3 characters but then it won't register the keystrokes.

Any clues?

Comment: "Stopped registering" as in it doesn't work at all? Can you try typing in your password albeit not with visual confirmation or 'blind'?

Comment: Is this exclusive to Skype?